# GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/image.jpg 404 (Not Found) in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a simple app that displays images. The images are in ***public/uploads***. When I copy the path `http://localhost:3000/uploads/image.jpg`  and paste in the URL I can see that image but I can't load it inside the page.

Here is my code:

```
<img src={product.image && product.image.imagePath} alt={product.image && product.image.imageName}/>
```

Comment: can you add more details to the problem, like what is the path exactly in imagePath prop?

Comment: `&&` or + ? in the {}

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine as in this snippet. Problem may be something else.

```js
const product = { image: { imagePath: "https://via.placeholder.com/150", imageName: "sample"}}

ReactDOM.render(<img src={product.image && product.image.imagePath} alt={product.image && product.image.imageName} />,   document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```